# Java double epsilon

Tags: java, floating-point

I'm currently in the need of an [epsilon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) of type `double` (preferred are constants in java's libraries instead of own implementations/definitions)

As far as I can see `Double` has `MIN_VALUE` and `MAX_VALUE` as static members.

Why there is no `EPSILON`?

What would a `epsilon<double>` be?

Are there any differences to a `std::numeric_limits< double >::epsilon()`?

Epsilon: The difference between 1 and the smallest value greater than 1 that is representable for the data type.

Comment: i'm vorting it down - ask clear questions!

Comment: In fairness, it's clear if you know what an epsilon is (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon).

Comment: Edited the Q. Sorry, I personally don't know other useages of an epsilon other than small error values (and therefore didn't think of this..)

Comment: hm, yes, maybe i was a bit emotionaly yesterday, i hope i didn't hurt anybody... thanks for clearing your question!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm presuming you mean epsilon in the sense of the error in the value. I.e [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon).

If so then in Java it's referred to as ULP (unit in last place). You can find it by using the `java.lang.Math` package and the `Math.ulp()` method. See [javadocs here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ulp(double)).

The value isn't stored as a static member because it will be different depending on the double you are concerned with.

**EDIT:** By the OP's definition of epsilon now in the question, the ULP of a double of value 1.0 is 2.220446049250313E-16 expressed as a double. (I.e. the return value of `Math.ulp(1.0)`.)

Comment: Seven minutes ago, the OP edited their question to define “epsilon” as  “The difference between 1 and the smallest value greater than 1 that is representable for the data type”. That value is constant.

Comment: @Pascal Indeed. I have added the edit to my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

By the edit of the question, explaining what is meant by `EPSILON`, the question is now clear, but it might be good to point out the following:

I believe that the original question was triggered by the fact that in C there is a constant `DBL_EPSILON`, defined in the standard header file `float.h`, which captures what the question refers to. The same standard header file contains definitions of constants `DBL_MIN` and `DBL_MAX`, which clearly correspond to `Double.MIN_VALUE` and `Double.MAX_VALUE`, respectively, in Java. Therefore it would be natural to assume that Java, by analogy, should also contain a definition of something like `Double.EPSILON` with the same meaning as `DBL_EPSILON` in C. Strangely, however, it does not. Even more strangely, C# *does* contain a definition `double.EPSILON`, but it has a different meaning, namely the one that is covered in C by the constant `DBL_MIN` and in Java by `Double.MIN_VALUE`. Certainly a situation that can lead to some confusion, as it makes the term `EPSILON` ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

Without using Math package:

```
Double.longBitsToDouble(971l << 52)
```

That's 2^-52 (971 = 1023(double exponent bias) - 52, shift by 52 is because mantissa is stored on the first 52 bits).

It's a little quicker than Math.ulp(1.0);

Also, if you need this to compare double values, there's a really helpful article: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/

Answer (score 0):

double: The double data type is a double-precision 64-bit IEEE 754 floating point. Its range of values is beyond the scope of this discussion, but is specified in the Floating-Point Types, Formats, and Values section of the Java Language Specification. For decimal values, this data type is generally the default choice. As mentioned above, this data type should never be used for precise values, such as currency.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

looking up at IEEE 754 you'll find the precision of epsion...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

binary64:

- Base(b)=2
- precision(p)=53
- machineEpsion(e) (b^-(p-1))/2=2^-53=1.11e-16
- machineEpsilon(e) b^-(p-1)=2^-52=2.22e-16

Comment: Please add your answer to your answer - I haven't found the word "epsilon" (or "epsion"...) in your Wikipedia link, nor do I think that you understand the question.

Comment: i should vote down this answer as well, because it's merely some google research - not even one part thinking in it....

Comment: Are you talking about your own answer?