# How to get floating point error size at a specific value in Java?

Tags: java, floating-point, precision

Is there any Java built-in functions or better solutions for finding the floating point error?
Or, in other words, is there a way to find out the smallest value that I can add to a `double` variable that wouldn't be neglected due to floating point rounding?

Right now I've figured that a fine way to get it would be to flip the last bit in it, subtract that from the variable, and return the result as `double` too.

```
double getFloatPointError(double in){
  long bits = Double.doubleToLongBits(in);
  bits^=1;
  return Math.abs(in-Double.longBitsToDouble(bits));
}
```

I don't think this is a good solution though, as the output result itself is `double`, and therefore also prone to floating point errors and may give an incorrect result. Also, I'm probably reinventing the wheel with this approach, which is something I'd like to avoid.

**Clarification:** I know what floating-point values are, I know that they shouldn't be used when accuracy matters, and I know that for such purposes I should be using `BigDecimal` instead. Please, refrain from posting general floating point related information and recommendations, as they aren't likely to include the answer to my question.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180950/java-double-epsilon/25181067 ?

Comment: If precision is even remotely important, I'd be using `BigDecimal` instead of a `double`

Comment: @dtanabe Yeah, that seems to be a duplicate of that. I'm sorry, didn't know that it's called "Epsilon".
Although, their question was about the constant value of error near `1.0l`...

Comment: This article is really good on floating point precision:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: A word of caution: "the smallest value that I can add to a double variable that wouldn't be neglected" depends on the current value of that variable. For example, if the current value is very large, even +1 can be neglected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `Math.ulp`:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ulp(double)

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the thing I'm looking for.
Except, isn't the return value still a `double` i.e. also has some error of itself?

Comment: I think it depends on what you need the information for, and what you mean by error. For example, even `BigDecimal` can't cope with a number like 1/3 without an "error", because `BigDecimal` is limited to those numbers that are representable as (a x 10^n), where a and n are both integers.